# How can I add “Toggle On/Off Code Lens” as a quick command button on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, codelens

I would like to have a quick command button displayed on my Menu bar to turn on/off the Code Lens. I understand there is a keyboard shortcut available for it:

The EditorContextMenus.CodeLens.CodeLensOptions command for keyboard shortcut, but I cannot make it as a quick command button.

It will be very awesome I can see a quick button on my VS Menu to quickly toggle it. (instead of remember it as keyboard shortcut)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746690/visual-studio-2015-codelens-toggle-on-off-with-keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is as hard as it looks - even though the command definitely exists, it is nowhere to be found in any of the menus when clicking "Add Command...". But this is a fixable oversight.

Here's what I did:

- Made a copy `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`
- Added a random command to my menu bar
- Removed "CodeLens Options..." from the respective menu using the command editor:
  [image]
- Closed all instances of Visual Studio for changes to be flushed to disk
- Ran an XML formatter on both files and then a diff on them
  (note: some diff tools like Beyond Compare have a built-in XML formatter)
- The diff revealed the command's GUID and CmdPri:

  ```xml
  <remove Cmd="{7660636A-8C08-4430-A56F-146E42A8B2C5}:00000001" CmdPri="01000000" Group="{7660636A-8C08-4430-A56F-146E42A8B2C5}:00002000" GroupPri="01000000" Menu="{7660636A-8C08-4430-A56F-146E42A8B2C5}:00003000" IsPartialRemoval="false"/>
  ```
- Modified my new command's `Cmd` and `CmdPri` to be that of the removed CodeLens command:

  ```xml
  <add Cmd="{7660636A-8C08-4430-A56F-146E42A8B2C5}:00000001" CmdPri="01000000" Group="{D309F791-903F-11D0-9EFC-00A0C911004F}:00000174" GroupPri="09000000" Menu="{D309F791-903F-11D0-9EFC-00A0C911004F}:00000001"/>
  ```

And voila - the command is now residing in the appropriate toolbar *and* you can move/modify it as you please:
[image]
You can now also go and reset the original CodeLens menu that you have removed it from.

Comment: omg this is such a hardcore hack. Amazing you even found out this approach!

Comment: this is such a shame that Microsoft didn't even tried to fix this simple lack of feature...