# Prevent Visual Studio from counting references of certain methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, codelens

In Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Microsoft introduced a feature named [CodeLens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx). A handy feature which (among others) has the ability to count the number of times a method is referenced in your project.

At the moment we're using VS2015 Pro and I'm working in a big solution with multiple projects in it.

**The problem**

Consider the following class:

```
public class MapItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool MainItem { get; set; }
    public int? MapId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Provider: {Provider}, Value: {Value}, MainItem: {MainItem}";
    }
}
```

CodeLens would count the number of times every property is referenced and adds it above each properties' declaration. I've also overridden the `ToString()` method to easily read the values when printing.

Right now, every time when I open a file with a `ToString()` declaration or when I make changes to one, Visual Studio starts counting the references of *every occasion where* `ToString()` *is used*. Even when this specific method in this class is not used.

This results in Visual Studio using all my CPU (95%+) and becoming unresponsive for a few minutes.

**My Question**

I have already learned [how to disable CodeLens reference counting completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references), but this is not what I want. What I would like to know is if there is any way to tell CodeLens to stop reference counting for a *single method* in general, and `ToString()` specifically (an attribute or blacklist perhaps?). This way Visual Studio won't have to go through the hassle of counting every time an overridden method is referenced. Alternatively, I would like to see the amount of references to `MapItem.ToString()` only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off CodeLens-References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references)

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this too. CodeLens is really unperformant at such situations and I don't know why it just doesn't stop counting after ~50 references or any other limit you could configure. I disabled it completely as the only solution.

Comment: @BugFinder How so? I stated from the start that I already knew how to do that and have said so too. I'm looking for a different solution here.. Either way, I've updated my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like, it's impossible.
You can't disable reference counting for a method, and you can't disable reference counting at all. This option is disabled:

[image]

I have found [this feature request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/7875225-allow-to-disable-codelens-show-references). And Visual Studio Team won't do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what I already found out too :( 
If there is no one else having a better solution, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Baksteen I think, you can ask VS Team about it