# P4VS code lens integration shows all file-level changes for each function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, codelens, p4vs

*(I've looked far and wide but I can't even find anyone having the same problem, not to mention a fix or anything. Closest is [this](https://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/6036-p4vs-codelens-support-for-vs2019/) thread which just announces the feature...)*

The way it currently works for me, the VS2019 code lens integration of P4VS (for C++ at least) is almost completely pointless. *Each function* has an indicator added, but the information in each is identical - namely the change history of the *entire file*:

[image: this]

According to [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019), I would expect to either get function-level change information *that pertains only to that function* or a single change summary of the file at the bottom of the editor. But instead I get the worst combination of both.

I'm mainly surprised that I can't find anyone else talking about this, so I assume something is misconfigured on my part. Can't find anything in the configuration options though...

Is this just a bad implementation by Perforce or is something wrong on my end?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that it can be turned off by Visual Studio options.

[How to turn off CodeLens-References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references)

Text Editor > All Languagues > CodeLens

Comment: Ah, I have just found out that it can be turned off by Visual Studio options..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references

Text Editor > All Languagues > CodeLens

That was all I wanted..