# How to disable show reference checkbox of codeLens option in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, codelens

I am trying to disable show reference in visual studio 2013.
Tools-> option -> Text Editor -> All Language -> over here show reference checkbox is disable  so I am not able to unchecked that  option. please let me know how to enable this option .
I also Attached snap of that option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off CodeLens-References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17848184/736079

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361255/how-to-disable-codelens-references-display-in-c-sharp?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

*Show References* does a lot of heavy lifting for all the other lenses. It constructs the call tree that's used to compute the Tested By/Tests relation as well as the reference count and the Test Status. As such it cannot be disabled without turning off the other options.

There is currently no way to disable CodeLens on a per-language basis. Currently CodeLens only supports VB.NET and C# and it's an all-or-nothing thing, since it depends on Roslyn under the hood.

Apart from doing that heavy lifting, the Reference Indicator is also put in place as a placeholder to prevent the editor from "stuttering" while the other lenses are loading. In an early beta it worked that way and that was incredibly annoying. There has been a version where they showed just empty space, and that was quickly replaced by always showing the reference indicator. Both because it should always be available and also because it's quick to compute and available offline.

I suggest you file a specific request for the changes you want to see on the [Visual Studio User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio). I believe now is the perfect time to send Microsoft feedback on this topic, they're in between releases.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot disable only reference checkbox, but you can change color of it, make the color real close to background color so you can see but only when you give very good look at it.