# Hide code editor overlays in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to disable the new code editor overlays in Visual Studio showing the number of references and the SCM state? And what's the official name of this feature?

[image: Overlays in VS2015]

Searched the preferences and the `View` menu, but didn't find anything.

Comment: The function is called CodeLens.

Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847927/how-to-hide-reference-counts-in-vs2013

Comment: Ah, thanks. Wrong search terms I guess :)