# Visual Studio 2013: Annoying line break

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ide

I came across an annoying setting in VS2013, I already tried to look for the correct setting in the Options window (TOOLS-> OPTIONS) that controls it, and also tried to Google this issue but simply couldn't name it well to get any results, hope any of you could help.

As said, I'm using VS2013, mostly for C#, and it seems that my IDE is configured to virtualize a line-break, though there's no line-break.

[image]

And while I do create a line-break, it still doesn't show up well
[image]

So this is pretty annoying, I'm kinda lost, could anyone guide me?

Comment: Looks like this space is for the reference overview. I'm using the 2015 Enterprise, but in 2013 Ultimate this feature is also available. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/PzQjtpa.png)

Comment: I do use VS2013U, but there's no reference line as u can see

Comment: Try deactivating it [How to hide reference counts in VS2013](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17848184/1875118)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was code due to CodeLens.

[I simply disabled it on VS2013](http://developerpublish.com/visual-studio-2013-tips-tricks-enable-disable-code-lens/)