# How to hide CodeLens reference counts in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, codelens

Visual Studio 2019 has a *feature* where it inserts lines showing you *"reference counts"*:

[image]

How do i turn them off?

### What have you tried?

- Right click the reference count line
- Click **CodeLens Options**

  [image]
- The **CodeLens** options dialog appears

  [image]

Note that the option `Show C# and Visual Basic references` is disabled and cannot be unchecked.

How do i uncheck it?

### Bonus Reading

- [How to hide reference counts in VS2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847927/how-to-hide-reference-counts-in-vs2013) *(the exact same question, but for VS2013, where the answers work)*
- [Cannot untick "Show C# and Visual Basic References"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-untick-show-c-and-visual-basic-references/590497)
- [Why can I not disable the Codelens show references](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/why-can-i-not-disable-the-codelens-show-references/173747)
- [Cannot untick "Show C# and Visual Basic References" #36378](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36378)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer remains, when Codelens is enabled, reference count is always shown. The feature has been unchanged largely since introduction and this has always been the case.

I'm not 100% sure about the reasons, but what I remember it has to do with reserving the screen realestate in case new indicators are activated later on due to context to prevent the code you're working on from jumping around.